# InheritedWidget not accessible from new Route

Tags: flutter, bloc, inherited-widget

I'm building a basic Flutter app with Bloc pattern. This is my structure so far.

[image]

`MainProvider` contains the `Repository`, which I can pass in every `Bloc` of every sub page (one Bloc per page, basically).
The problem is that, if I want to access `MainProvider` like this:

```
final provider = MainProvider.of(context);
```

from MenuPage, or OtherPage, which I access to by navigating from HomePage with

```
Navigator.push(context, 
    MaterialRoutePage(
       (context) => MenuPage(homePageParam); //or OtherPage(homePageParam)
    );
```

the `.of` method returns `null`.

How can I properly access that `InheritedWidget`? Should I do another type of `Navigator.push`?

Comment: Can you include the code of your `MainProvider.of()` function ?

Comment: For `InheritedWidget.of` to work, the build context you're passing should be below the Inherited widget in the widget tree.
Assuming from the diagram above. The `MainProvider` and `MenuPage` are on different routes which won't work.
You will have to place the InheritedWidget above your `MaterialApp` widget if you want it to be passed to all routes.

Comment: @MazinIbrahim, it's just the usual `context.inheritWidgetFromExactType(MainProvider) as Main Provider;`
@Sakchham I was afraid I had to do it...not much code change, but would that mean that I can call `Navigator.of(context).push` with a new `MaterialPageRoute` and still access the `InheritedWidget`?